# What is the size of a double pointer string?

Tags: c, string, strlen, arrays

Assume I have `char **argv`. How do I determine its size?

I have a string - an example would be: `sleep 30 &` that is held in `argv`. I would like to be able to access the last array in `*argv`. In this case, the last array contains `&`. How can I access it? `strlen(argv)` doesn't seem to work properly. `sizeof()` obviously wouldn't work properly because `**argv` is a pointer.

Note: I am not talking about `**argv` as an argument in main(), therefore, I do not have `argc` or any other indicator of how long the string is.

Comment: @vireshas that doesn't allow you to access the last array of *argv. Just shows you its length.

Comment: I already tried it - doesn't work.

Comment: @vireshas That sounds ... off. There is a difference between `NUL` and `NULL` (and `char*` and `char**`).

Comment: This is silly. OP is basically asking "How do I know where the end of a list is?"  The answer is either that you remember how long the list was, or you have a sentinel value that comes after the last member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: Edited to work with a custom array of strings.  A `NULL` pointer indicates the end of the array.  Although this declares an array of 4 strings, this method could be used with a dynamically sized array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char* custom[4] = { "sleep", "30", "&", NULL };
    int last;
    for (last = 0; custom[last + 1]; last++);
    printf("%i - %s\n", last, custom[last]);
    return 0;
}

// ./a.out
// > 2 - &
```

For this to work for you, you would have to edit your program to explicitly include an extra `NULL` string in your `char**` when you build it.  Without that indicator, the address after the last string wouldn't necessarily be `NULL`, so you could include garbage in the count or cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: Doesn't work with my custom made char **. Yours is from main.

Comment: For this method to work properly for you I think you'll need an extra member at the end of the array indicating that the array is closed.  I'll make a new example.

Comment: what if there's no NULL at the end of custom?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp the only other option is knowing how many strings are in the array -- see Matt McNabb's comment above

Comment: @SlaceDiamond, what if I don't know its size and there's no NULL as the last element?

Answer (score 1):

Passing in a count like argc is the most common usage - but you say you don't have that.

Then the usual way is to have the last element of argv to point to NULL to indicate it is the last array element.

```
int argc = 0;
while (*argv++) {
 argc++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `strtok` to tokenize the arguments and work through them until you have the last one.

[Referemce for strtok](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strtok.html).

Comment: Wouldn't that be quite stupid though when you don't really have to tokenize anything?

Comment: @Nayefc If you have to discard all the other tokens, yes. But, it's generally the case that all argument tokens are there to be consumed in some way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
   char *argv[] = {"abc","123","xya"};

    //prints the last string
   printf("%s",a[strlen(*a)-1]);
```

// if you are sure that the array of strings ends with NULL

```
   char *temp = 0 ;
   while(*argv){
        temp = *argv;
        (*argv)++;
   }
  //temp has the last string
```

Comment: This makes the assumption that there is a "trailing" `NULL`. That should be documented, at least. (The post says it "not an argument ... in `main`".)

Comment: I am compiling with -Werror. This gives *argv++ an error that it is not being used afterwards.

Comment: @pst i edited the answer .. i have added a comment as u had mentioned :)

Comment: `printf("%s",a[strlen(*a)-1]);` - this only works because your first string has the same number of characters in it as the list has strings. Change `"abc"` to `"supercalifragilistic"` and see what happens